# Use devise gem with API only Rails 5 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, rails-api, ruby-on-rails-5

I am learning Rails 5, trying to implement authentication in my API only application. Currently I am using the `devise_token_auth` gem for it.

My question is: is it possible to use the `devise` gem for authentication in Rails 5 API only application in the same way as in traditional rails applications?

If not, what is best way to implement authentication in Rails 5 API only application?

Comment: I think it's possible using device in API only app

Comment: Any reference link you can provide ?

Comment: You can use traditional way for login out and register

Comment: Do you want to implement token-based authentication or session-based authentication ?

Comment: As its API only app, I think session-based would not be possible, so its token based authentication.